# Background image not scaling to phone.

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a site that is built on html5 wordpress blank.

http://thesemachinesarewinning.com/

As you can see it's resizes and scales to the browser window as it should, however on mobile, the background image does not scale and the logo and nav only fully show on landscape view.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width:1140px) {

}
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) {

}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution:144dpi) {

}

/* css for the nav and background image

body {
    font:300 11px/1.4 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background:url('img/home-bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed center right;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.page-section {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index:100;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    margin:3px auto 0px auto;
    float:left;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width:1280px;
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your current view port with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do anything.